# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el estilo de un material mat-slide-toggle en Angular 15?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Necesito modificar los estilos de un mat-slide-toggle, pero no he encontrado cómo, he intentado varias maneras que he encontrado en internet pero no se ven reflejados. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo cambiar los estilos del mat-slide?

Comment: ¿Cuáles estilos quieres cambiar?